# Asyncio Task in coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

I debug at line with `note <10>`, Task `spinner` starts to print.But I don't know why.How to understand it?

---

**Code below from Book `Fluent Python`**

```
import asyncio
import itertools
import sys


@asyncio.coroutine  # <1>
def spin(msg):  # <2>
    write, flush = sys.stdout.write, sys.stdout.flush
    for char in itertools.cycle('|/-\\'):
        status = char + ' ' + msg
        write(status)
        flush()
        write('\x08' * len(status))
        try:
            yield from asyncio.sleep(.1)  # <3>
        except asyncio.CancelledError:  # <4>
            break
    write(' ' * len(status) + '\x08' * len(status))


@asyncio.coroutine
def slow_function():  # <5>
    # pretend waiting a long time for I/O
    yield from asyncio.sleep(3)  # <6>
    return 42


@asyncio.coroutine
def supervisor():  # <7>
    spinner = asyncio.async(spin('thinking!'))  # <8>
    print('spinner object:', spinner)  # <9>
    result = yield from slow_function()  # <10>
    spinner.cancel()  # <11>
    return result


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # <12>
    result = loop.run_until_complete(supervisor())  # <13>
    loop.close()
    print('Answer:', result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. In the line with note `<8>` you explicitly schedule the coro `spin` in the event loop. Why don't you expect it to execute?

Comment: Why spinner execute when code runs to the line with note <10> instead of line with note <8>

Comment: It's asynchronous execution. `supervisor`, `slow_function` and `spin` all run concurrently inside the same event loop in your code.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what your question is? Do you expect `spinner` to start executing sooner, or later, or not at all?

Comment: In this case, `supervisor` and  `spinner` are 2 tasks scheduled in event loop.So when code comes to `yield from slow_function()`, task `supervisor` suspend and event loop continues to execute task `spinner`.Am i right?@user4815162342